# Connect to WiFi with "networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 ssid password" without entering the password in plaintext?

Tags: command-line, osx, wifi, password

How to connect to a WiFi network using `networksetup -setairportnetwork en0 ssid password` without using the password in plaintext?

Comment: Is your station encrypting the channel? Use `WPA2-AES`,`WPA2-TKIP`, `WEP`? See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_Key_Integrity_Protocol for another good possibility.

Comment: `networksetup -setairportnetwork`is a macOS-specific command, tag added. Also it looks like the options supported by the `networksetup` command are highly dependent on macOS version, so please identify which macOS version(s) you're asking about.